# File system Errors monitoring in Zabbix

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

In zabbix(linux), how can we monitor the file system health, so that we can check for any file system level errors like the one mentioned below happening in some specific disk partition.

> EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): mb_free_blocks: double-free of inode 0's
>   block

Is there any specific template available for this. Or should we be going forward with writing custom script to monitor /var/log/messages log for specific error strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no template so far that does this (as of version 5.4).

You should write a custom script that does pattern matching. For what you're doing I even suggest investing a bit more time into a pattern matching script that allows for configurations - will save you a lot of time later on with custom Zabbix monitoring items.

But for beginners, a simple `grep` [UserParameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/userparameters) will do the job.